# Rutas existen pero laravel me dice que no

Tags: laravel

tengo las siguientes rutas :

```
//Admin Routes..
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/',[AdminController::class,'index'])->name('admin.index');
    Route::get('/show/user/all',[AdminController::class,'showAllUsers'])->name('admin.show-all-users');
    Route::get('/show/user/{id}',[AdminController::class,'showUser'])->name('admin.show-user');
    Route::get('/show/user/verified',[AdminController::class,'showVerifiedUsers'])->name('admin.show-verified-users');
    Route::get('/show/user/unverified',[AdminController::class,'showUnverifiedUsers'])->name('admin.show-unverified-users');
    Route::get('/show/user/with-tasks',[AdminController::class,'showUsersWithTasks'])->name('admin.show-users-with-tasks');
    Route::get('/show/user/without-tasks',[AdminController::class,'showUserWithoutTasks'])->name('admin.show-users-without-tasks');
});
```

Y cuando intento acceder a las rutas debajo de la ruta con name `admin.index`. No me las reconoce.

He probado con diferentes comandos de artisan para refrescar la memoria cache por si acaso, pero nada va.

Comment: Llevo tiempo que no he tocado laravel pero me ha resultado interesante la pregunta ¿Es posible que estés utilizando mal el nombre o ruta de acceso? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-prefixes .En la documentación se observa que definen "admin." terminando en "punto" para luego acceder al nombre de cada ruta. No estoy seguro que una vez has definido el prefijo "admin" has de especificar de nuevo "admin.index". ¿Quizás solo con ".index" sea suficiente?

Comment: Gracias por contestar @Sergio, la ruta en principio esta bien ya que accedo mediante su route name y me lleva a la url correcta, pero no lee el controlador correctamente, he puesto dd()´s para debugear pero no salen, asi que no se que puede ser, estoy mirando porque nunca me habia pasado esto.

Answer (score 0):

Buuenas, vengo a responser esta pregunta porque creo que es curioso lo que he encontrado entre comentarios de foros, por lo visto las rutas de laravel que se usan vars o directivas propias de laravel se tienen que colocar en la ultima posicion, es decir, en mi caso no funcionaba porque esta ruta:

```
Route::get('/show/user/{id}',[AdminController::class,'showUser'])->name('admin.show-user');
```

estaba en segundo lugar, y tiene una variable en su url que es `{id}` , pues todas las rutas que tengan cosas de esas deben de ponerse al final del grupo.